How to edit a keyboard layout on Windows 10?
I need to add just one symbol from one of the standard Windows layouts to another one. It should be triggered by Alt Gr + one of the letter keys pressed.
PowerToys doesn't let you type symbols from other layouts. AutoHotKey doesn't allow input or output keys not from currently selected layout. Is there another solution?

Which character is that, and do you have unicode input?

@harrymc it's 040E in capital and 045E in small.

Have you tried AutoHotkey?

@DavidPostill now I did, but it didn't work, I added details to the question

MKLC works perfectly. What is your problem with it?

@ComputerUser121212 to my knowledge, it can create custom layouts from scratch, but not take an existing layout as a template. Correct me If I'm wrong. I hope there is a more elegant solution out there.

AutoHotKey sends the character or its unicode representation, it doesn't need to type it via the keyboard. The question is if this character is displayable in the font.

MKLC most definitely allows you to do that. Go to File > Load existing keyboard. There you can choose from a list of keyboards installed on your PC.

@ComputerUser121212 you were right, can you please write it as an answer, or I can do it, if you want

You can use Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator v. 1.4 to add that new key to an existing layout.
First, go to File > Load existing keyboard and select the keyboard layout you want to modify from the list. Then click the key where you want to add the new character and click the three dots to show all possible shift states and options.
Once you have it the way you want, go to Project > Build DLL and Setup package. That will create a Setup.exe file that, when run with administrative privileges, will add the newly created layout to your system. Now just enable it from settings (a restart might be necessary after installing the layout).
